# Cambiar mensaje de fecha invalida en momentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

la libreria momentJS cuando la fecha es invalida lanza el mensaje de **"fecha invalida"**

`moment(null).locale("es").format("DD/MM/YYYY");`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y yo quisiera cambiar ese mensaje a **"No Aplica"**

¿alguien sabe cómo puedo cambiar ese mensaje sin necesidad de usar un condicional o algo por el estilo?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38955292/12418873

Comment: ¡¡Muchas Gracias!!